# Even after removing an erroneous line of code, an error still persists

Tags: android

I'm working on an app to keep score for a card game, and it was working fine until now. I have several places where I check to make sure that the number put in won't cause any errors, that is, they don't break the rules of the game. If such input is encountered, the app opens an `AlertDialog` telling the user of the problem. However, I had tried to call `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`, which threw a `NullPointerException` since I was creating the `AlertDialog` with an `AlertDialog.Builder`. I removed the statement, but every time I try to run the app and intentionally make the `AlertDialog` pop up, the `NullPointerException` message shows up and the app crashes.

Here's the method that creates the `AlertDialog`:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_error))
            .setMessage(errorText)
            .setCancelable(false);

    switch (errorType)
    {
        case 1:
            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    PlayerNumErrorDialogListener activity = (PlayerNumErrorDialogListener) getActivity();
                    activity.onFinishPlayerNumError();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    CurrentTotalScoreErrorDialogListener activity = (CurrentTotalScoreErrorDialogListener) getActivity();
                    activity.onFinishCurrentTotalScoreError();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    PlayerScoreErrorDialogListener activity = (PlayerScoreErrorDialogListener) getActivity();
                    activity.onFinishPlayerScoreError();
                }
            });
            break;
    }

    // This is the line I have removed.
    // getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    return builder.create();
}
```

And here's the stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gcapps.richcardsscorekeeper, PID: 5268
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.gcapps.richcardsscorekeeper.ErrorDialog.onCreateDialog(ErrorDialog.java:94)
    at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Any ideas as to why the `NullPointerException` is *still* being thrown? I've tried restarting the app, rebuilding the project, invalidating the cache and restarting Android Studio, and even copying the entire class, deleting it, and pasting it into a new file (in case the old one was corrupt for some reason).

Comment: Have you tried running clean?

Comment: "at com.gcapps.richcardsscorekeeper.ErrorDialog.onCreateDialog(ErrorDialog.java:94)" This says the error occurs in the `onCreateDialog()` method of the `ErrorDialog` class. This is on line 94 of ErrorDialog.java. What line is this?

Comment: Also, try cleaning and rebuilding your project. If you still get the exact same error, try uninstalling your app then reinstalling the new version.

Comment: also if you have instant run on, you could try turning it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `getDialog()` from inside `onCreateDialog()` since you haven't returned the alert dialog to let your `DialogFragment` know what it is yet. Just call it on the `Dialog` instance,

```
Dialog d = builder.create();
d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
return d;
```

Comment: That solves it. I'm still confused as to why the error keep showing up, though, even after I removed the call.